# connection refused on couchDB

Tags: couchdb

I have couchdb which worked well until Thursday.
Nobody seems to have touched it but now when I try a:

curl http://admin:mymdp@127.0.0.1:5984/

I get an error
[image]

My configuration files looks fine, i already changed the bind_address to 0.0.0.0.
and restarted my couchDB.

I have read online to check my port

so i did a netstat -an | grep 5984 who return nothing but then i don't know what to do.
What's the next step?

Comment: First, this question probably belongs on ServerFault, since it's not about programming. Second, [don't paste images of errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860).

Answer (score 0):

If there is no port in *"LISTENING"* then it means that the service is down.

Try to check with:
`systemctl status couchdb`

and if it were down:
`systemctl start couchdb`